# iOS build script fails on defaults read command

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, macos, build

I have an iOS app with a Build phase script that reads a plist file using the following command:

```
defaults read "/full/path/to/plist/file" CFBundleExecutable
```

...but it fails with the following error message:

```
The domain/default pair of (/full/path/to/plist/file.plist, CFBundleExecutable) does not exist
```

The full path of the file is correct and I double checked that the file indeed contains  the key `CFBundleExecutable`. I also tried with other keys such as `CFBundleName`. Running the command both with and without `.plist` at the end of the full path fails.

I also ran the command in Terminal to see if it works generally, but the command fails there as well.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that macOS (or the `defaults` command line tool) seems to have a bug. Folders that are "special" such as `Documents` and `Desktop` act differently within the command line environment and as such I observed the following:

- If Info.plist is located in a subfolder of `Desktop` or `Documents` the `defaults read` command will fail
- As soon as you place `Info.plist` in any other folder (such as a `Developer` folder) the same `defaults read` command will succeed

I am not sure if this is due to the fact that both of these folders require special permissions (macOS asks if an app requests access to either of these) or if it is because they are part of iCloud Drive and perhaps there is some weird symlinking in the background.

Either way, if you run into a similar error, just try to place your project in a subfolder of `~/Developer` (or any other non-default, non-special folder).